# Is there any way to disable "Watch Next" block at the end of video using YouTube Android Player API?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

In my app I'm using YouTube Android Player API library from here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/
I have a fragment that extends YouTubePlayerFragment. All works fine, but I need to make some improvements to app.

At the end of some videos I see block "Watch Next" with the link to another video, so I'm curious - does we have a possibility to disable this feature?

I created another solution using WebView, and display video using it - in this case I'm able to turn off any other additional links using "rel=0" in video url, but I want to use native solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS ` style for the player? https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But it doesn't helps me.. I found that this block comes from "Featured content" of channel. So if we will turn off it in channel settings, it doesn't appear. In my case, I was able to talk with channel owners, and decide this question directly with them. But it's only my case - not sure that all people has possibility to decide it as I decide it.. So any other solutions still welcome.

Comment: There is one last resort, which involves using a ViewTreeObserver and hiding that particular view. Basically, you attach a `onGlobalLayoutChangeListener` to the YouTubePlayer and you monitor the changes in order to identify which view is displaying that message. Then, hide it.